# How to display file name instead of count missing keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript

I am trying to create an application that allows you to upload json files and then checks which file is missing a particular key.

The application works almost perfectly, but I have no idea how to indicate in which file specifically the key is missing, so it currently prints such information

admin-page is missing in 1 file(s) you uploaded

And I would like it to look like this

admin-page is missing in english.json (english.json is file name)

My component looks as follows:

```
import { Box, Button, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { compareKeys, getKeys } from './service/keysService.ts';

function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<File[]>([]);
  const [missingKeys, setMissingKeys] = useState<{ [key: string]: number }>({});
  const [fileContents, setFileContents] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const handleFiles = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const uploadedFiles = e.target.files as FileList;
    setFiles((prevFiles) => [...prevFiles, ...uploadedFiles]);
    Array.from(uploadedFiles).forEach((file) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        const content = reader.result?.toString();
        setFileContents((prevContents) => [
          ...prevContents,
          reader.result as string ?? "",
        ]);
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    });
  };

  const handleCompareKeys = () => {
    compareKeys(files, setMissingKeys, fileContents);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{
      display: "flex",
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center",
      "flexDirection": "column"
    }}>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleFiles} multiple />
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleCompareKeys}>
        Compare Keys
      </Button>
      <Box sx={{
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}>
        {files.map((file, index) => (
          <TextField
            key={index}
            sx={{
              width: "50%",
            }}
            label={file.name}
            value={fileContents[index] || ''}
            multiline
            rows={10}
            margin="normal"
            InputProps={{
              readOnly: true,
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </Box>
      <Box>
        {Object.keys(missingKeys).length > 0 && (
          <div>
            <h2>Missing Keys:</h2>
            <ul>
              {Object.entries(missingKeys)
                .sort(([key1, count1], [key2, count2]) =>
                  key1.localeCompare(key2)
                )
                .map(([key, count]) => (
                  <li key={key}>
                    {key} is missing in {count} file(s) you uploaded
                  </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        )}
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
} 

export default App;
```

And here's the service that handles everything

```
export const getKeys = (obj: { [x: string]: any }): string[] => {
    const keys = [];
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        keys.push(key);
        if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            keys.push(
                ...getKeys(obj[key]).map((subkey: any) => `${key}.${subkey}`)
            );
        }
    }
    return keys;
};

export const compareKeys = (
    files: File[],
    setMissingKeys: (missingKeys: { [key: string]: number }) => void,
    fileContents: string[]
) => {
    if (files.length < 2) {
        console.log("Please upload at least two files");
        return;
    }

    const readers = files.map((file) => new FileReader());
    const objects: any[] = [];

    readers.forEach((reader, i) => {
        reader.onload = () => {
            try {
                const data = reader.result;
                let obj = null;
                if (typeof data === "string") {
                    if (data != null && typeof data === "string") {
                        obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Invalid file format");
                    }
                }
                objects[i] = obj;
                if (objects.length === files.length) {
                    const allKeys = new Set(
                        objects.map((obj) => getKeys(obj)).flat()
                    );

                    const missingKeysObj: { [key: string]: number } = {};
                    for (const key of allKeys) {
                        let count = 0;
                        for (const keys of objects.map((obj) => getKeys(obj))) {
                            if (!keys.includes(key)) {
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (count > 0) {
                            missingKeysObj[key] = count;
                        }
                    }
                    setMissingKeys(missingKeysObj);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(`Error parsing JSON in file ${files[i].name}:`, e);
            }
        };

        reader.readAsText(files[i]);
    });
};
```

How can I capture a specific file name. I think one solution might be to modify `const [fileContents, setFileContents] = useState<string[]>([]);`.

In addition, I would appreciate small suggestions on how I can improve this code to make it a bit more readable

I am also posting the tests for getKeys to make things clearer

```
import { getKeys, compareKeys } from "./service/keysService.ts";

describe('getKeys', () => {
    it('returns an array of keys from an object', () => {
        const obj = {
            foo: 'bar',
            baz: {
                qux: 'quux',
            },
        };

        const result = getKeys(obj);

        expect(result).toEqual(['foo', 'baz', 'baz.qux']);
    });

    it('handles nested objects correctly', () => {
        const obj = {
            foo: {
                bar: {
                    baz: 'qux',
                },
            },
        };

        const result = getKeys(obj);

        expect(result).toEqual(['foo', 'foo.bar', 'foo.bar.baz']);
    });

    it('returns an empty array for an empty object', () => {
        const obj = {};

        const result = getKeys(obj);

        expect(result).toEqual([]);
    });

    it('handles arrays correctly', () => {
        const obj = {
            foo: ['bar', 'baz'],
        };

        const result = getKeys(obj);

        expect(result).toEqual(['foo', 'foo.0', 'foo.1']);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code you've posted to the [minimum necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @computercarguy
The code required to open the problem is all without testing file